# Oracle DateTime type using ConnectorX in Python

Tags: python, oracle, connector

I've been using Pandas and SqlAlchemy to get data from a Oracle database and save it as Parquet files for analysis.

I've read that Connectorx is the fastest and most memory efficient way to load data from databases into Python and I want to try it.

My routine with sqlalchemy takes about 6 min to get 2M rowx x 8 columns from Oracle DB. ConnectorX takes 1.15 min to get the same data. It was quite impressive.

But, when I checked my files generate with ConnectorX the datetime column was loaded as only date.

Is there way to get datetime from ConnectorX using a Oracle Db?

**SqlAlchemy**
694882   TESTE CPD 4 **2020-08-31 17:33:53**   99999
694888  TESTE CPD 10 **2020-08-31 16:10:30**   99999
694888  TESTE CPD 10 **2020-08-31 16:08:19**   99999

**ConnectorX**
694882   TESTE CPD 4  **2020-08-31**   99999
694888  TESTE CPD 10  **2020-08-31**   99999
694888  TESTE CPD 10  **2020-08-31**   99999

Comment: In SQLAlchemy with Oracle, tune [`arraysize`](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/dialects/oracle.html#options-consumed-by-the-sqlalchemy-cx-oracle-dialect-outside-of-the-driver) which helps performance. And use python-oracledb since the new Thin mode can reduce data copies, see see the [release announcement](https://cjones-oracle.medium.com/open-source-python-thin-driver-for-oracle-database-e82aac7ecf5a) and [Using python-oracledb 1.0 with SQLAlchemy](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/using-python-oracledb-1-0-with-sqlalchemy-pandas-django-and-flask-5d84e910cb19).

Comment: More info on `arraysize` is in the underlying driver [doc](https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/tuning.html#tuning-fetch-performance).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: @ChristopherJones, thank you ! I will check those links